# How to get RevoluteJoint to move to a certain angle

Tags: java, algorithm, math, box2d, physics

I have a `RevoluteJoint` (the Box2D/AndEngine kind) That needs to be moved it a certain angle from time to time. The direction and speed it is moving at when it needs to move to said angle can be anything. The tricky part is to get it to slow down at the right moment, so that the joint does not overshoot the target and start oscillating around the target angle.

The way i see it, the variables are:

- V - Angular velocity (in radians/sec) the joint is trying to achieve. Negative is going counter clockwise.
- W - Actual angular velocity. Negative if moving away from the target angle.
- D - Distance to go (in radians) until target angle is achieved
- Q - Motor torque
- L - Angular momentum
- Did i miss any?

Any physics buffs or mechanical engineers who could tell me a formula that will allow me to adjust Q and V based on these variables, so that the joint will stop at the right place?

PS: If V is set to 0, the joint will try to hold its position

Comment: Revolute joints have motors and limits, are you using those? Limits would prevent overshooting the target (although there can be a tiny bit of overshoot for a frame or two if the body was rotating quickly). You can use the joint motor to set the Q and V values you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Damped harmonic oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator)

What you are describing sounds like a damped harmonic oscillator with overdamping (damping ratio ζ > 1). The target angle of the `RevoluteJoint` should at all times be set as the resting displacement for the oscillator.

In the equations described on Wikipedia, the correspondences with your variables is as follows.

- Mass m is the inertial mass of your revolving object
- Force F is the motor torque
- Displacement x is the current angle of your joint

The other variables' correspondences should be straightforward given those. Note you missed mentioning the inertial mass in your description.

Be careful not to confuse the meaning of the undamped angular frequency ω<sub>0</sub>, the angular frequency ω, and the resonant frequency ω<sub>r</sub> in your scenario.  These are **not** angular frequencies because you have a rotating joint. These are angular frequencies in the displacement domain, corresponding to the oscillations of the joint angle.

Comment: Based on what I read, wouldn't it be underdamping? Seeing as it moves slightly past the point and then back and forth a few times before settling.

Comment: @Jarmund From you: "The tricky part is to get it to slow down in time, so that it does not overshoot and start oscilating aroind the target angle." From Wikipedia: "Overdamped (ζ > 1): The system returns (exponentially decays) to steady state without oscillating. Larger values of the damping ratio ζ return to equilibrium slower."

Comment: Bad wording on my part, then. My problem is with underdamping, for sure. It is a result of picking some static values for slowing down the joint, and underdamping is better than overdamping.

Comment: @Jarmund Alright. Nonetheless, the damped harmonic oscillator model will do the job for you. If you do want oscillatory behavior, you can choose underdamping. The physics equations stay the same.